# Does "Wave of light" pillar of the ancients, stack?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

When playing a Monk, with [Wave of Light](https://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/wave-of-light), Pillar of the Ancients rune... if you drop 3 pillars at the same time, do all 3 pillars hit the enemy for stacked damage?

Comment: From the description it seems the 3 pillars hit the enemy. Each pillar will deal 635% wdamage and  785% wdamage over 3 seconds. But the pillars from my understanding don't affect each other.

Comment: Alright. Thank you! Did you want to put that as an answer, and I can accept the answer? Or did you want me to do that?

Comment: I didn't put has an answer yet, because I haven't confirmed it yet gamewise... work been a little busy.